# Error: Changing the event handler name failed. Event handler names are read-only

Tags: ssis

Error: Changing the event handler name failed. Event handler names are read-only.

Error: The result of the expression "@[$Package::OnError_Name]" on property "\Package\Load Multiple Excel Files\Load_tbl_stg_Prospects.EventHandlers[OnError].Properties[Name]" cannot be written to the property. The expression was evaluated, but cannot be set on the property.

Anyone come across this while simply executing a package?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted package.   When you say simply executing the package, do you mean this is a package that used to work before?

Comment: Yes. I ran it numerous times before. I set up XML configurations during deployment and when I deployed it, I got this error. I'm trying to understand it but there's nothing similar on the web.